# SubtractFrom::rvalue with Compile

Tags: warning-messages, compile

I want to compile the code described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/180041/8822), but I get the error:

> SubtractFrom::rvalue: 1.`*^8 is not a variable with a value, so its
>   value cannot be changed.

A minimal non working example could be:

```
ClearAll[s]
fun = Compile[{{s, _Real}}, s -= 1]
fun[10]
```

Where is my error?

Comment: Please do make an effort to construct a minimal example (this applies to your last question as well).  This error occurs when the left-hand side of `-=` is not a symbol, e.g. `2 -= 1` or `With[{x=2}, x -= 1]`.

Comment: `enp` is a function argument, not a variable.  `enp -= something` is not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why does this happen?

To expand on the point made by @Szabolcs in the comments: In Mathematica, functions defined via downvalues, such as

```
f[x_] := x^2
```

are replacement rules. When an expression such as `f[2]` is encountered, the rule is applied, and placeholders are inserted before any evaluation is done. So the first thing the right hand side "sees" is `2^2`, *not* `x^2`. Notice how the "variable" `x` is already gone. Pure functions ([`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html)/`…&`), and by extension compiled functions, work in a very similar fashion. This means that you cannot modify the value of such a parameter, as you're trying to do with `x -= 1`.

The following examples demonstrate that the behavior/issue is really much more fundamental that just `Compile`:

```
f[x_] := (x -= 1)

f[10]
(* During evaluation of … SubtractFrom::rvalue: 10 is not a variable with a value, so its value cannot be changed. *)
(* 10 -= 1 *)

f2 = Function[x, x -= 1]
(* Function[x, x -= 1] *)

f2[10]

(*During evaluation of … SubtractFrom::rvalue: 10 is not a variable with a value, so its value cannot be changed. *)
(* 10 -= 1 *)
```

Coming from another language, this might be unexpected, as function parameters are typically mutable variables.

#### Solution/Workaround

The most straightforward solution is to just create a local variable using [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) with the value of the parameter:

```
fun = Compile[{{s, _Real}}, Module[
  {vs = s},
  vs -= 1
]]

fun[10]
```